# Trying to send curl POST command in Cocoa App

Tags: xml, macos, cocoa, curl, posix

I am trying to use cURL to send a POST request to my Yamaha receiver from a Cocoa application. I am using NSTask to accomplish this and believe I have the syntax correct:

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c", @"curl -v -X POST -H \"Content-type:text/xml\" --data 'xml=<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><YAMAHA_AV cmd=\"PUT\"><Main_Zone><Power_Control><Power>On</Power></Power_Control></Main_Zone></YAMAHA_AV>' http://172.19.24.23/YamahaRemoteControl/ctrl", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];

[task launch];
```

I have it assigned to a button in my application, it compiles successfully but when I press the button I get this in the log.

```
 2013-12-06 11:06:27.907 MyApp[18361:303] user clicked powerOnReceiver button
2013-12-06 11:06:27.909 MyApp[18361:303] Couldn't posix_spawn: error 13
2013-12-06 11:06:27.911 MyApp[18361:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff897c641c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff88e96e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff897c62cc +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff87e71214 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:] + 3167
    4   MyApp                               0x0000000100001c9a -[Receiver powerOnReceiver] + 218
    5   MyApp                               0x0000000100007053 -[AppDelegate powerOnReceiver:] + 67
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff863733d0 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 327
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8637324e -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff863bfd7d -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 128
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff863d9715 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2316
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff863d8ae7 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 487
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff863d81fd -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 706
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff86359d08 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 11296
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff862f8744 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2021
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff86148a29 -[NSApplication run] + 646
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff86133803 NSApplicationMain + 940
    16  MyApp                               0x00000001000063e2 main + 34
    17  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff85ed05fd start + 1
)
```

I think my path is correct here so I am not sure when I am getting the "Couldn't posix_spawn: error 13" message. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error 13 is `EACCES` (Permission denied).

The `launchPath` attribute should be set with the path of the executable (`curl` here), but you have set its folder `/usr/bin/` instead.

Other thing: you have some problems with the way you build your arguments list. Since `NSTask` takes care to build the proper `argv[]` list behind the scenes, you must take care to break things argument by argument.

Also you should not do extra quoting. In other words you must pass `@"Content-type:text/xml"` instead of `@"\"Content-type:text/xml\""`.

To sum up you should rewrite your task as follow:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/curl"];

NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-v", @"-X", @"POST",
                        @"-H", @"Content-type:text/xml",
                        @"--data", @"xml=<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                         "<YAMAHA_AV cmd=\"PUT\"><Main_Zone><Power_Control>"
                         "<Power>On</Power></Power_Control></Main_Zone></YAMAHA_AV>",
                        @"http://172.19.24.23/YamahaRemoteControl/ctrl", nil];

[task setArguments:arguments];

[task launch];
```

*PS.: is there any reason why you do not use `NSURLConnection` to perform your `POST`?*

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked perfectly. I went with NSTask because I am more familiar with it and it seemed to be a cleaner way to lay out the POST rather than NSURLConnection. Is there any benefit to performing it as a NSURLConnection?

Comment: Great! Pro-tip: you can use http://httpbin.org/ to debug your requests. Vs. NSURLConnection: indeed it is way cleaner and portable to use a native HTTP client w/ underlying HTTP framework than issuing system commands. Plus you get progress handlers, better error reporting, etc. If you are familiar with libcurl you may want to consider using [BBHTTP](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/BBHTTP) that is a nice Objective-C wrapper for iOS/OSX apps.